# correct way to get selected option in jquery from an object

Tags: javascript, jquery, select

I've seen on StackOverflow and googling around that the most used way to get the selected text from a `<SELECT>` element with jquery is like this

```
$("#cboId :selected").text()
```

what I have is not the id, but an object. I have an object, say

```
var myCombo= $("#cboId");
```

coming from an earlier piece of code.

I've done like this to get the selected text, but is ugly:

```
  $("#" + myCombo.attr('id') + " :selected").text() ;
```

Is there any cleaner way to do it?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
var selectedText = $(":selected",myCombo).text();
```